# Iterate JObject without foreach

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing, jsonconvert

This piece of code is working fine **i'm iterating JObject using foreach loop**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await clientHelper.PostAsJsonRequest("home/LoadPatientDetailData/2232565", new { });

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
            JObject y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(x.ToString());
            int i = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> xs in y)
            {
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    //data.outstandingTasks = xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<OutstandingTask>>();
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    data.outstandingPrompts = xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<OutstandingPrompts>>();
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    data.outstandingRecalls = xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<OutstandingRecalls>>();
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    //data.diagnosis = xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<Diagnosis>>();
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    data.measurments = xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<Measurments>>();
                }
                i++;
            }
            PatientDetailData xx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PatientDetailData>(x.ToString());

        }
```

is there a way to iterate it **without using foreach** i try few methods but **they didn't work**. e.g

```
KeyValuePair<string, JToken> q = y.First;
KeyValuePair<string, JToken> w = y[0];
KeyValuePair<string, JToken> h = (KeyValuePair<string, JToken>)y[0];
KeyValuePair<string, JToken> hs = y[0] as KeyValuePair<string, JToken>;
KeyValuePair<string, JToken> e = y["key"];
KeyValuePair<string, JToken> r= y.Value;
```

**But none of them worked**

Comment: How does your json look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Json is too big to show you here but i can explain when i convert my response to **JObject it has 5 objects** and the **2nd child of each object is the array that i want to access** and you can see inside foreach loop `xs.Value.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).ToObject<List<OutstandingRecalls>>()` 
this way i have to use i to check which iteration i am at and then convert the response to some object accordingly now what i am saying is **can't i access JObject children using its index like y[0] etc** so i have to just write five lines instead of this foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly? You could probably use certain LINQ queries after you cast it to a `<Key,Value>` pair

```
var y = xs.Where(d => d.Key == "some_key").Select(v => ((JValue) v.Value).Value);
```

Comment: Exactly i just want to cast it to **<Key,Value>** pair but not using foreach loop can't i access JObject (which is y in this case) using index?? as you can see i am using foreach for casting but i am not able to cast it using index as at the **end of the question** i show you some ways i tried to cast it but none of them worked